# Backbone.js - How to model a nested list

Tags: list, model, backbone.js

I am trying to model a multi-level nested list in Backbone and wondering how best to model this with Collections/Models.

I currently have (in coffeescript)

My Collection

```
class App.Collections.List extends Backbone.Collection
   model: App.Model.ListItem
```

My Model

```
class App.Model.ListItem extends Backbone.Model
   defaults: 
     name: "foo"
     bar:  "bar"
     children: new App.Collections.List # This doesnt work because I need to load Models before Collections
     parent: this # initialized by param hash
```

I currently initialize the View with e new App.Collection.List (of ListItem Models) which gives a list of depth 1. When I click on a ListItem I want it to perform a HTTP GET, that it can populate it's children with, and so on and so forth. Currently I have 3 levels deep but it could grow deeper.

Should I use something like SuperModel [1] or Backbone-relational [2]?

[1] http://pathable.github.com/supermodel/

[2] https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational